# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification not called on switching keyboards on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios11

I'm handling keyboard frame changes with `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. When user opens, hides keyboard or switching keyboards by pressing on the "globe" key, everything works fine - methods called correctly. But if user **long-presses** on globe and selects keyboard that is **higher** than current (for example, English keyboard switching to Emoji keyboard), method `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` not called. So new keyboard covers 40-50 px of UI.

This happens only when switching from lower to higher keyboard and only on iOS 11.

How to handle keyboard switching in iOS 11 the right way?

Update: Found the same issue in Apple Contacts app (while creating or editing contact) and Calendar app (while creating new event) in simulator (don't have iOS 11 on real device).

Comment: The 'UIKeyboardWillShowNotification' is also not called if you hide the keyboard and try editing second time without leaving the ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported this to Apple some time ago, and my bug report was closed as a duplicate, so they're aware of it. Nothing we can do about this except wait for an iOS update.

For reference, here's the openradar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5026499329523712

Comment: So... ok. Just waiting.

Comment: Issues is still reproducible on ios 11.2.2, iPhoneX.
Working fine on Whats app and allo. but breaking on Messenger and other such apps.